Android Firebase Push Notifications - some devices aren't getting all notifications. Is there a sending limit?
I have an app in which the users can interact with each other through comments. Every time a user gets a comment/reply, he gets a notification. Some users who are very active are sometimes complaining that they don't get some notifications when they got a comment/reply. Sometimes even for days without any.
I'm always using the latest library and the latest method of sending them from the server side.
I myself get every notification when a user writes a comment to me, since they don't interact with me as much as with each other.
So my question is, is there a limit how many notifications one device can receive in a period of time?
I've read here about the limit of 240 per minute and 5000 per hour, is it up to date? It's nowhere near of how many notifications they are suppose to receive.
We all know that in programming, something can't work how it feels like, so when something doesn't always work then it must be based on limitations, set in the algorithm.
